# Need to import data from excel to array in C#

Tags: c#, excel

I want to import data from excel with multiple rows and columns, and i want to put it into an array.
I have th idea of each position of array will have a line(with multiple rows). Is there any simple source code to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question. You want to import data from excel to what? Also C# and Excel is a very widely documented topic. You should google first. Tip: convert your excel file to a CSV and then google on `CSV to C#`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ClosedXML nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML)

On [project's github](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) you can find some samples.

Also, your question will soon be closed, due to a fact that it doesn't have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you guys!
I will check your sugestion. Cumpz